# Setting web.config file to check if a cookie is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-config, authorization

I'd like to set my web.config file to redirect to login.cshtml if a cookie is not set. How can I do this? What I have at the moment is exhibiting some behaviour I don't understand, also. I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Login.cshtml" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
             <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What is happening is the user is being redirected to

```
"Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.cshtml"
```

So the default.cshtml is being rendered, with a weird login page placed centrally within it? It's probably to do with the structure of my program, but I don't really understand what is being called that could render this weird HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `loginUrl` should be the path that would take you to the Login view, as if you were trying to navigate to it via a web browser. Which, if I had it to guess, would be something like mywebsite.com/Account/Login. So the corresponding code in web.config would be

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
</forms>
```

This would be based on default routes and so forth. If your site has modified routes and/or view engine overrides in place, you may experience different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are referencing "Login.cshtml" in the loginURL, which is a view.  In MVC you don't route a user to a view (that is selected in the controller).  You have to point the user to the path/Controller/Action.  As mentioned in the other post here, that is usually "~/Account/Login" if you use the standard project template (the tilde indicating the application root).